# How can I configure my HelpNDoc HTML build to use Microsoft Clarity?

Tags: html, helpndoc, ms-clarity

How can I configure my [HelpNDoc](https://www.helpndoc.com/) HTML build to use [Microsoft Clarity](https://clarity.microsoft.com/utm/gad/%7BConversion_label%7D?utm_source=googleads&utm_medium=paidsearch&utm_campaign=ctysgb&utm_content=googl1&gclid=Cj0KCQiArt6PBhCoARIsAMF5wajTyNN2al6_4LdG3OMO513h0-tTo9QxvemJCKPqltjlUNQyr7gMYZAaAv7nEALw_wcB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you already have some knowledge of working with custom templates in HelpNDoc. You can learn more about templates [here](https://www.helpndoc.com/documentation/html/Workingwithtemplates.html).

Start by editing the `topics.pas.html` file:

[image]

Locate this bit in the file:

```
<!-- Content style -->
<link href="css/hnd.content.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

You need to add a new bit of code just before. For example:

```
<!-- Microsoft Clarity -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
      c[a]=c[a]||function(){(c[a].q=c[a].q||[]).push(arguments)};
      t=l.createElement(r);t.async=1;t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
      y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
  })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "~~~~~~~~~~");
</script>
```

Microsoft Clarity will provide you with the actual code to use. It will look like the above code, except `"~~~~~~~~~~"` will be you personal ID value.

Save your script and now your HTML build will have support for Microsoft Clarity.

---

### Using Template Variables

It is possible to improve the template and make it work on multiple projects. This can be done by replacing the hard-coded personal ID  with a **template variable**.

This is discussed here ([Alternative: add a template variable to define the default Robots meta tag value](https://www.helpndoc.com/news-and-articles/2020-09-23-how-to-define-robots.txt-and-robots-meta-tags-in-your-html-documentation/)).

#### Step 1

Add a new variable to your template. I called it `MSClarityID`:
[image]

#### Step 2

Change the `topics.pas.html` file:

```
  <!-- Microsoft Clarity -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
        c[a]=c[a]||function(){(c[a].q=c[a].q||[]).push(arguments)};
        t=l.createElement(r);t.async=1;t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
        y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
    })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "<% Print(HndGeneratorInfo.GetCustomSettingValue('MSClarityID')); %>");
  </script>
```

We changed the hardcoded project ID to:

```
<% Print(HndGeneratorInfo.GetCustomSettingValue('MSClarityID')); %>
```

#### Step 3

Finally, specify the value for the variable in the HelpNDoc's projects **Template settings** tab:

[image]